# group by on clustering key is not reading from metadata

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have defined cluster key on one of the column "time periods" , when i use `where` clause it operates on metadata that I can see in history profile of below query

```
select count(*) from table where time_period = 'Jan 2021'
```

but when i use `group by` to know count of each month , it scan all the partition.

```
select time_period , count(*) from table group by time_period
```

Why the second query is not the metadata operation ..?

Comment: your second query has no filter, so no micro-partition pruning can happen:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#query-pruning

Answer (score 1):

```
select time_period , count(*) from table group by time_period;
```

is a full table scan.

```
select count(*) from table where time_period = 'Jan 2021'
```

is a full scan on partitions with the time_period equal to one value, so the meta data is searched to find the matching partitions, thus the pruning.

if you table has values from 'Jan 2020' to 'Jan 2021' and assuming those are dates not strings (which would be very bad for performance), and assuming you data is clustered on time_period (or naturally inserting in "months") then

```
select time_period, count(*) 
from table 
where time_period >= '2021-06-01'
group by 1 order by 1;
```

should only read ~50% of your partitions, as the assumed order of the data, means only half the tables need to be read.

Comment: Yes i tried above query , it is using now only one partition and took 12 seconds from 3 minutes  .. But still using warehouse..  Isn't snowflake should optimize the query itself of using where clause ?

Comment: @snowflake_user some trivial queries do not need to look at the data as the meta data contains the answer. But the meta data seems to mostly reflect top(n) values and ranges of column values. Thus I have seen `select count(*) from table where id = x` I have sent take no compute when x is a very common value, and do a full table scan when it don't exist but is in the of the value range that do exist. The point is snowflake is optimized for map/reduce/merge and you should structure you data for the class of questions you most want to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the "meta-data" vs "scanning" question. This is based on years of working with query optimization, and is "very well educated speculation".
There is big difference between "COUNT(*)" and "COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY". The latter is much more complex and handles much more complex queries.
Optimizers evolve over time to handle special cases, but they start out focusing on more common types of queries.
The non-GROUP query against a non-keyed but well clustered table with use a scan. It's a specialized optimization, meaningful, optimization for a special case.
But the same specialization is not present in the GROUP BY, which addresses a much broader class of queries, with GROUP BY and WHERE clauses for multiple non-cluser-key columns.
The COUNT(*) GROUP BY would need to add a special check for this particular query form; once anything else is added, the meta-data would not be sufficient.
So no specialized optimization for this specific case in COUNT(*), GROUP BY